# Nginx server wont start with one particular site enabled

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, lets-encrypt, ubuntu-20.04

Got a head scratcher that I can't seem to figure out.

If I enable this specific site "example" the nginx server wont restart or anything until I disable it. This problem only shows up if I try to enable SSL with letsencrypt.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS if this makes a difference, and the project is a Laravel 5.7

nginx -t returns all successful

What is causing the problem / where can I look to start to get answers?

**Working config:**

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name example.ca *.example.ca;
root /var/www/example/public;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}
}
```

**Broken config:**

```
server {
server_name example.ca *.example.ca;
root /var/www/example/public;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ca/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ca/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
if ($host = www.example.ca) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


if ($host = example.ca) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

listen 80;
server_name example.ca *.example.ca;
return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

**journalctl --xe:**

```
-- A start job for unit nginx.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 1074.
Sep 04 03:32:07 YDS-SERVER nginx[14844]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 04 03:32:08 YDS-SERVER nginx[14844]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 04 03:32:08 YDS-SERVER nginx[14844]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 04 03:32:09 YDS-SERVER nginx[14844]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 04 03:32:09 YDS-SERVER nginx[14844]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 04 03:32:10 YDS-SERVER nginx[14844]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Sep 04 03:32:10 YDS-SERVER systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit nginx.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Sep 04 03:32:10 YDS-SERVER systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit nginx.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 04 03:32:10 YDS-SERVER systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit nginx.service has finished with a failure.
```

Comment: Kill the process that is still listening on port 443.

Comment: when I check, there isn't anything on 443...